# Does IronRuby support Attributes?

Tags: attributes, ironruby

I searched everywhere from google to this site but seems no answer for it. Does anyone know if IronRuby supports clr class attributes? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to apply CLR attributes in IronRuby today. IronPython support it experimentally with its `clrtype` module, which uses its own way of [overriding the underlying .NET class for a Python object](http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html#clrtype).

If one would want to implement this in IronRuby themselves, it'd be a large undertaking, but not impossible. If anyone is interesting, please ask about it on the [mailing list](http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/ironruby-core/) to get started.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have another question on [using ErrorListener in IronRuby](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9324536/1201766). Could you help?